# I have written a solid calculator but I missed the part where I can loop it?

Tags: python, loops, continue

```py
# Python program for simple calculator

# Function to add two numbers
def add(num1, num2):
    return num1 + num2

# Function to subtract two numbers
def subtract(num1, num2):
    return num1 - num2

# Function to multiply two numbers
def multiply(num1, num2):
    return num1 * num2

# Function to divide two numbers
def divide(num1, num2):
    return num1 / num2

print("Welcome, please choose the operation:\n" \
        "1. Addition\n" \
        "2. Subtraction\n" \
        "3. Multiplication\n" \
        "4. Division\n"  \
        "5. Exit\n")`enter code here`


# Take input from the user
select = int(input("Please, Type the choice:"))

number_1 = int(input("Enter number 1: "))
number_2 = int(input("Enter number 2: "))

    if select == 1:
    
        print(number_1, "+", number_2, "=",
                        add(number_1, number_2))
    
    elif select == 2:
        print(number_1, "-", number_2, "=",
                        subtract(number_1, number_2))
    
        elif select == 3:
            print(number_1, "*", number_2, "=",
                            multiply(number_1, number_2))
        elif select == 4:
            if number_2 ==0:
                print('You cannot divide by zero')
            else:
                print(number_1, "/", number_2, "=",
                                                divide(number_1, number_2))
        elif select == 5:
            print("Thanks and goodbye")
```

Answer (score 0):

##### Effective Solution

Menu operations are performed in the `while` loop defined within the `main()` method.

```py
import operator

def main():
    while True:
        print("1. Addition\n2. Subtraction\n3. Multiplication\n4. Division\n5. Exit\n")
        select = int(input("Please, Type the choice:"))
        
        if select >= 1 and select <= 4:
            number_1 = int(input("Enter number 1: "))
            uOperator = input("Enter operation type: ")
            number_2 = int(input("Enter number 2: "))
            ops = { '+' : operator.add, '-' : operator.sub, '*' : operator.mul, '/' : operator.truediv }
            print(number_1, uOperator, number_2, "=", ops[uOperator](number_1, number_2))
        elif select == 5:
            print("Thanks and goodbye!")
            break
        else:
            print("You have entered incorrectly! Please select the range [1, 5]")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Usage of the program:

```
Enter number 1: 3
Enter operation type: *
Enter number 2: 5
3 * 5 = 15
```

##### Solution with Current Approach

```py
def add(num1, num2):
    return num1 + num2

def subtract(num1, num2):
    return num1 - num2

def multiply(num1, num2):
    return num1 * num2

def divide(num1, num2):
    return num1 / num2

def main():
    while True:
        print("1. Addition\n2. Subtraction\n3. Multiplication\n4. Division\n5. Exit\n")
        select = int(input("Please, Type the choice:"))
        
        if select >= 1 and select <= 4:
            number_1 = int(input("Enter number 1: "))
            number_2 = int(input("Enter number 2: "))
        
            if select == 1:
                print(number_1, "+", number_2, "=", add(number_1, number_2))
            elif select == 2:
                print(number_1, "-", number_2, "=", subtract(number_1, number_2))
            elif select == 3:
                print(number_1, "*", number_2, "=", multiply(number_1, number_2))
            elif select == 4:
                if number_2 ==0:
                    print('You cannot divide by zero')
                else:
                    print(number_1, "/", number_2, "=", divide(number_1, number_2))
        elif select == 5:
            print("Thanks and goodbye!")
            break
        else:
            print("You have entered incorrectly! Please select the range [1, 5]")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```